# How do I add rows to UIPickerView from UIAlertController

Tags: iphone, uipickerview, uialertcontroller

I have a `UIPickerView` that gets its data from an array that is defined in

```
friends = [NSArray arrayWithObjects: @"jim", @"joe", @"anne", nil];
```

I have a button under the picker that is supposed to add new friends to the picker.
When the button is pressed a `UIAlertController` pops up and the user can enter the new friends name. I can save the text as a string but I can't add it to the array. I've also tried using `NSMutableArray`'s.

I'm new to this so all input would be great. I've looked at similar questions for help but nothing has worked.

Thanks!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Ok so I will try to explain this:

You declare a `NSMutbleArray`, you can't expect to use a `NSArray` because is not mutable, and you need to modify the content.

```
    NSMutableArray *array;
    UIAlertController * view;
    @implementation ViewController


    - (void)viewDidLoad {
        [super viewDidLoad];
        NSArray* friends = [NSArray arrayWithObjects: @"jim", @"joe", @"anne", nil];
        array = [NSMutableArray arrayWithArray:friends];
// I added a UIPickerView in the StoryBoard, connected it to a property and the delegates and datasources.
        self.pickerView.delegate = self;
    }
```

Then you declare dataSource of UIPickerView:

```
- (NSInteger)numberOfComponentsInPickerView:(UIPickerView *)pickerView{

    return 1;

}

// returns the # of rows in each component..
- (NSInteger)pickerView:(UIPickerView *)pickerView numberOfRowsInComponent:(NSInteger)component{

    return array.count;

}
- (NSString *)pickerView:(UIPickerView *)pickerView titleForRow:(NSInteger)row forComponent:(NSInteger)component{

    return array[row];

}
```

So, then you present your UIAlertController, in this case I will dismiss it in the `Return` of the `TextView`.

```
//This is an action connected to the button which will present the ActionController
- (IBAction)addFriend:(id)sender {



    view =   [UIAlertController alertControllerWithTitle:@"Add Friend" message:@"Write the friend to add"preferredStyle:UIAlertControllerStyleAlert];

    [view addTextFieldWithConfigurationHandler:^(UITextField *textField) {
        textField.placeholder = @"Friend";
        textField.delegate = self;
        textField.tag = 01;
    }];

    [self presentViewController:view animated:YES completion:nil];

}
- (BOOL)textFieldShouldReturn:(UITextField *)textField{

    if(textField.tag == 01){

        [array insertObject:textField.text  atIndex:array.count];
        [view dismissViewControllerAnimated:YES completion:^{
            [self.pickerView reloadAllComponents];
        }];

        return YES;

    }

    return YES;

}
```

This is more or less what you can do, I was the most specific I could be because you said you are a begginer.

Hope it Helps.

Comment: thanks for your detailed answer! It was exactly what I was looking for. Before I was trying to save the new friend with a `UIAlertAction`. Your method is much easier. Thanks again.